# Excel array function that assigns employee code to customer based on rank series assigned to employee

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to Assign employee code (`EmpID`) to my customer database in Excel

I've the list of customers from each store which is ranked and it should be allocated to the employees of the respective store.

I've customer database in the following format Column name is given in brackets

```
(A).       (B).       (C)
Store - CustomerID - Rank
 A.   - A01.       - 1
 A.   - A02.       - 2
 B.   - B01.       - 1
 B.   - B02.       - 2 and so on
```

I've employee database in the following format

```
 (D).      (E).       (F).      (G)
Store.  - EmpID. - Rankfrom - Rankto
A.      - E1.    -   1      - 10
A.      -E2.     -.  11.    - 16
B.      - E3.    -.  1.     - 8 and so on
```

I'm trying to add one more column to employee table where `EmpId` is assigned based on store and rank of customer in relation with rank range assigned in table 2

I've come up with formula, but not working as I expected . Please help since I'm new with array functions

```
{=Index(D:G,Match(1,((F:F>=C2)*(G:G>=C2)*(D:D=A2),0)2)}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the desired output?  My guess is that you want to 1: match store, 2:match rank range of employee to customer rank?

Comment: Desired output will be to add an employee code against each customer ( matching store and range of rank allotted to each employee )

Comment: when you mentioned "but not working as I expected".. what is exactly the output? any screenshot? | Also I see in you example (correct me if I'm wrong), that E1 will serve A01, E3 will serve B01, and no one in the list is eligible to serve A01 or B02 right ?

Comment: Data is more complicated, I've recreated a similar model to understand with ease. Employee E1 is assigned with customer with rank 1 to 10 falling under store A (he will serve A01,A02,A03 till A10). Employee E2 will serve customer with rank 1 to 8 under store B (B01,B02,B03 till B08). In the actual scenario I've 202 employees in 42 stores with a customer base of 3200.

Comment: Please find the link to sample file created https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6beHgP0prXRTdxU1IzcGl0TGVIVG5BaW5SLXVLVjZncWM4/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @Daghan pls check the file uploaded

Comment: I would either A: Compile all the data into a pivot table and match by your criteria, or B: Write some short VBA if or case that loops through both tables and inserts Emp ID if a certain row matches by store and rank range, should be quite easy. C: it may be possible to solve by Excel formula but i can't figure it out.

Comment: @Daghan pls tag someone who can solve this

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Daghan I prefer getting it done through formulas , but I'm new with array function. If u check the workbook I uploaded the result is coming with some logic issues , with some minor adjustments it should work. Pls suggest someone who can help

Comment: I dont know anyone on here, Bounty the question or create a new one

Comment: Solved on my own. Thanks for the time

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. For anyone who have similar query

=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$500,MATCH(1,INDEX((C2>=$K$2:$K$500)*(C2<=$L$2:$L$500)*($F$2:$F$500=B2),0),0)),"")